# "Unfortunately, MainScreenActivity has stopped" ERROR message in Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried doing this code from this site: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ . Everything worked out properly but when i tried to VIEW and ADD products the emulator goes "Unfortunately, MainScreenActivity has stopped.

help please?? :D

here is my logcat file:

```
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 15: http://10.0.2.2 /try/get_all_products.php?
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at com.example.mainscreenactivity.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:60)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at com.example.mainscreenactivity.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:128)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at com.example.mainscreenactivity.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-26 15:53:16.227: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     ... 3 more
06-26 15:53:16.570: W/ActivityManager(276):   Force finishing activity com.example.mainscreenactivity/.AllProductsActivity
06-26 15:53:16.737: W/WindowManager(276): Failure taking screenshot for (266x425) to layer 21020
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space character after the ip address: `http://10.0.2.2*/`

Comment: tnx @maxado_zdl ! >.<